# A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '' could not be found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

Hello all I am new to the Xcode etc... I made a app now I am trying to distribute it ad-hoc I paid for the enterprise license, I see this is a problem with other people I just am too new to find out what to change. A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '4R7B8RY6Z1.com.LaneBob' could not be found is the error I created a provisioning profile '4R7B8RY6Z1.com.LaneBob.*' what do I change in the code or Xcode to fix this so I can build it? I am building to archive not to a device so I am not sure what to do.

Thanks for any help!

***EDIT***
I have checked these places:

1) info.plist
Make sure that your Bundle identifier matches what you have in your Provisioning portal. It should have what you entered online, not the yourcompanyname stuff.

2) Your target
Right click on your build target and select "get info". And then under the Build tab, find the Code Signing section. There should be one item that says Code Signing Identity. This is where you pick which signing identity to sign with and you want to make sure it matches the intended provisioning profile. If you don't see your provisioning profile listed, you didn't install it correctly. Your provisioning profile needs to be installed on the device for it to run, and in Xcode so it can sign the app with the provisioning profile.

Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your two points:

1) You should have com.LaneBob.yourappName in the info.plist file. For Ad-hoc distribution you can't have 'generic' names with wildcard characters. You don't need the beginning HASH part (4R7B8RY6Z1. in your case)

2)You pick code signing identity in XCode target preferences. 'LEFT' click on project, then go to the target of your app. Inside there, there are 'code signing identity' for different configurations. When you build and archive you typically build release mode and use distribution certificate.

All this can not solve your problem if you don't have provisioning profile installed in your mac. Just download it from the portal and double click on it to install it. Also with newer XCode you can just download all provisioning portals from organizer, by entering the user/password there.

Incidentally, I found you need to restart xcode sometimes to 'get' the keychain updates.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @DarthMikeCan you please suggest me for the best way that how to deploy an app using Enterprise program (299$) without adding device's UDID? I have searched alot but haven't got any good answer..thanks.

Comment: @APG You need to access developer portal, and create a special distribution profile. Then you have to compile your app against that profile. When applications have this profile embedded the check for UUID is not done.

Comment: @DarthMikeThanks for your time. what you mean by "special distribution profile"? Actually now from my developer portal, i have created a distribution pro. profile without adding any device UDID using InHouse instead of Ad-Hoc. And this certificate type is UniversalDistribution. Using this certificate my application .ipa file is working in any iPhone devices via iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility. Is it the correct solution to deploy our app for Enterprise program?

Comment: @APG What you describe seems to be correct for Enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error message when I was trying to build an app on my iPhone. Everything seemed to be in order, I.e. the certificates were all valid and present and so on, but I just couldn't get it to work.

I just couldn't find the option "iOS team provisioning profile" in **Project** > **Build Settings** > **Code Signing** > **Code Signing Identity** - this was the main clue to a solution. If you can't see that option there, check your Xcode **Organizer**.

Inside it, go to **Library** > **Provisioning Profiles**:

[image: prov profiles]

Now what you *should* see if everything were right is this:

[image: if all is well]

But if on the other hand you see an empty list, click the **Refresh** button in the lower right corner of the Organizer:

[image]

After said procedure, Xcode started churning out wonderful messages of "adding" and "finishing" and then my app appeared on my iPhone. The End.

Good luck!

Comment: @cubuspl42 I'm really glad that this helped you, since I remember how hopeless I felt before finding this out... :) Keep it real!

Comment: That's it, your answer is the most correct one for first time provisioning users like me. Thanks very much.

Comment: @TienDo I guess that's because at the time of writing I was myself a first time provisioning user. You're welcome!

Comment: Can you please suggest me for the best way that how to deploy an app using Enterprise program (299$) without adding device's UDID?thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with the Enterprise program, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to first BUILD the app with Cmd-B.

This popped up a keychain window access asking me to "Allow" (or "Always Allow") Xcode to access the keychain.

Only THEN could I actually run the program to launch it on my iPhone.

Apparently, hitting only run didn't do the trick.

(Btw, remember to first sign your app with the "iPhone Developer: Your Name ()" key.