# Certificates won't show in code signing identity in build settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm encountering the errors:

> No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

and:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

XCode isn't giving me any option other than "Automatic iOS Developer and Distribution" options in the 'Code Signing' area of the 'Build Settings'.

I've tried changing the bundle id to match the certificates exactly, as well as a more generic com.domain.appname ID, I've deleted and recreated the provisioning profiles - I'm really lost, it feels like it should be something really simply but I can't get my certificates to show in the settings.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Did you change your Mac recently? AFAIK the app id has to match perfectly.

Comment: Did you clean the project as sometimes it didn't update the matching provisioning profiles in the Xcode?

Comment: check the provisioning profiles are present in iphoneconfig utility...

Comment: Toby, I think this question has the relevant answers for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985611/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not/16488288#16488288

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing I would check is that your Cert in Keychain Access is present and is married up to your private key. If it's listed but your private key isn't paired with it you've likely changed your Mac's password recently and instead of pressing "Update Keychain" you may have clicked on "New Keychain". This will require performing the CSR process again and adding that new cert from the portal to the existing prov profiles. (A screenshot here may help).

Next I would make sure that XCode's Organizer is showing your provisioning profiles as valid with a green checkmark.  If they aren't valid XCode will tell you why. This could be anything from the missing private key to your cert wasn't added to the profile in the dev portal. (Another screenshot here may help).

If all of that looks good restart XCode. I've had problems with XCode not properly importing prov profiles until I give it a swift kick in the pants via restart.

Comment: Accepting this because it's the closest answer to my problem. I did in fact change the password on my Mac recently, and had some troubles with my Keychain, but after resolving those I still had the error. I had to completely re-create my certificates from scratch including requesting the certificate from the CA from my Mac in the keychain as you mention.

Comment: Xcode restart worked for me. There was Xcode update waiting quit iTunes, Simulator and restart it worked well for me.

Comment: "I give it a swift kick" And now this becomes a pun :P

Comment: My problem was that I had 2 certificates in Keychain. I deleted one of them. Then I went to Windows -> Projects and I deleted the Derived data of the project with problems. Finally I restarted the app and worked perfectly. I'm using Xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 16):

I was shocked when having the same problem and reading some answers here, too complicated. But I solved this much much simpler.

- Open Keychain Access. Delete iPhone Developer and iPhone Distribution certificates, although they are still valid.
- Open Apple Developer Centre. Download iOS Development and iOS Distribution certificates again. Yes, I download them again as they are written as XXXX-1.cer
- Drag them to Keychain Access to reimport them.
- Rerun XCode. Problem solved.

Comment: A word of caution with this answer if you have an Enterprise account: If you aren't on the Mac that the Enterprise CSR originated from or you have rolled your keychain password but have not submitted a new CSR you just nuked your enterprise cert and all of your apps. Make sure you have an export of the valid cert stowed away somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create a new iOS Provisioning Profile in apple portal then download and add it to the Organizer in XCode , my scenario was that I was importing the project from another user account and when Titanium was compiling the project had the iOS Provisioning Profile associated from the other user account therefore was crashing, so when I was ready to compile in the Run on iOS Device dialog I changed the Provisioning profile to the new one.
As it has been stated before, you need to see the green button (valid profile) in the Provisioning Profiles for your device .

Good luck! it took me two days to fix this!

Ren@ud

Comment: Presumably Toby has a valid provisioning profile and is unable to find it in Xcode.