# Provisioning Profile ERROR while running in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am using Xcode 4.6.3.
I am getting this error messages while running the application in iPad,But first it was running correctly. Now we have renewed our license so i have changed certificate and
profile.still the same error appears

[image: Error dialog]

Please help me...

Comment: see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985611/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode

Comment: delete the old provisioning profiles from your keychain, add new provisioning profiles, in XCode go to code signing identity and choose correct provisioning profiles. It will work

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow this step:-

- You Provisioning profile Generate with developer certificate from iTunes dev center.
- remove old install App from device may be you Ipad contain old profile reference.
- After connect your device to Xcode-Organizer->device->yuorIpad->Provisioning--check there old Provisioning profile is ther or not. if there then remove it.
- In your target And Project check-> your Identifier is currect or not for example **com.yourprofile.yourId**
- In Build setting you->code signing ->selection profile is correct identifier or not

Now just clean your Project. Build and run.

**EDIT**

*Do not forget to Adding New testing Device ID into your new Generate Provisioning profile. in iTunes Dev there is Column to adding Device and also asking Device while you Generate Provisioning profile. May be you forget this step.*

Comment: i have created created the certificate using the ipad 3... but its not running in that ipad... but working fine in ipad 2

Comment: you need to adding Device id i mean ipad3 id's into your Profile from iTunes dev

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you are generating provisioning profile after adding device, or when you're just renewing profile.
And your provisioning profile must be linked with certificate, that you have in keychain.
(certificate+key)
All devices must be readded on demand, after renewing dev program (!)
In general, It's pretty sraightforward (just try it from the clean sheet, delete all the old stuff)
1) cert signing request
2) appid (if new app, if old just skip, optional - apns stuff)
3) certificates dev/distr (import them)
4) devices 
5) provisioning profiles (import them)

in xcode choose in all positions needed profile, sometimes choosing parent option do not change profile for all fields of "Signing Identity" in xcode.

Deleting of old provisioning profiles is optional, it's not a problem when you have many of them
it's only problem when signing identities are more then one, ie: old expired and new one.
(In xcode 5 it will be easier to choose identity)

EDIT: it really seems like in build settings in code signing identity select options (some option) an old profile is chosen, and xcode gives this error.